# Camel-Castor getting error while unmarshalling and while marshalling also its not using mapping file

Tags: java, apache-camel, unmarshalling, fuseesb, castor

I have a problem with unmarshaling and then marshaling.

**My input:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GetDeadlineOffset>
    <deadlineCode>DC1</deadlineCode>
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="P1">Param 1</parameter>
      <parameter name="P2">Param 2</parameter>
    </parameters>
</GetDeadlineOffset>
```

**My mapping:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class name="com.evolvus.training.camel.domain.GetDeadlineOffset">
    <map-to xml="GetDeadlineOffset"/>
    <field name="DeadlineCode">
        <bind-xml name="deadlineCode" />
    </field>
    <field name="parameters" type="com.evolvus.training.camel.domain.Parameter" collection="collection">
        <bind-xml name="parameter" location="parameters">
            <class name="com.evolvus.training.camel.domain.Parameter">
                <field name="Name">
                    <bind-xml name="name" node="attribute" />
                </field>
                <field name="Value">
                    <bind-xml node="text"/>
                </field>
            </class>
        </bind-xml>
    </field>        
</class>
```

**My classes:
Parameter.java**

```java
public class Parameter {
   private String name = null;
   private String value = null;
  //setters and getters
}
```

**GetDeadlineOffset.java**

```java
public class GetDeadlineOffset {
   private String deadlineCode = null;
   private Vector<Parameter> paramList = new Vector<Parameter>();
   //setters and getters
}
```

**ISO3166Processor.java**

```java
public class ISO3166Processor implements Processor {
   public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
      GetDeadlineOffset iso4217 = (GetDeadlineOffset) arg0.getIn().getBody();
      System.out.println("Unmarshalled Object is: " + iso4217);
      arg0.setOut(arg0.getIn());
      arg0.getOut().setBody(gdo);
      arg0.getOut().setHeaders(arg0.getIn().getHeaders());
   }
}
```

route:

```
<bean id="currencyProcessor" class="com.evolvus.training.camel.processor.ISO3166Processor" />
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

   <dataFormats>
      <castor id="iso3166" 
         mappingFile="castor/castor-mapping.xml"
         packages="com.evolvus.training.camel.domain"/>
   </dataFormats>

   <route>
      <from uri="file:src/data/in?noop=true"/>
      <unmarshal ref="iso3166"/>   
      <log message="unmarshall" />
      <process ref="currencyProcessor" /> 
      <log message="processed" />
      <marshal ref="iso3166" />
      <log message="reachng output2" />
      <to uri="file:src/data/out?fileName=${id}" />
      <stop></stop>
   </route>
</camelContext>
```

**Exception:**

```
Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught:
java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.exolab.castor.mapping.Mapping.loadMapping(Mapping.java:276)
[org.apache.servi‌​cemix.bundles.castor-1.3.1_2.jar:] –

The class for the root element 'GetDeadlineOffset' could not be found.
File: [not available]; line: 2; column: 20}
at org.exolab.castor.xml.Unmarshaller.convertSAXExceptionToMarshalException(Unmarsh‌​aller.java:794)
[org.apache.servicemix.bundles.castor-1.3.1_2.jar:]
```

If I marshal it says consider switching to using Marshaller instances and calling one of the `marshal()` methods*. Please give me resolution for this also. How to call non-static method of marshall using camel?

Comment: Add your exception to question!!! Not to comments.

Comment: Thanks Melr for your comment.I added exception to question itself.Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: someone plz help me in resolving this issue...

Comment: I noticed this blog entry which seems to contain the same example that you are working on ... might be good for a reference? http://ennovatenow.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/using-the-camel-castor-component-to-marshal-and-unmarshal-xmls/

Comment: Thanks Shiraz.M  i already tried that,for my program i m getting same exception.

Answer (score 0):

This Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.exolab.castor.mapping.Mapping.loadMapping(Mapping.java:276)
[org.apache.servi‌​cemix.bundles.castor-1.3.1_2.jar:] –
```

indicates that the castor can't find your `mapping.xml`. Make sure it gets included in your jar file / classes directory.